# Altering Tables in From clause and altering filters affects SQL performance?

Tags: sql, left-join, sybase

I recently asked a question on SO here:

[SQL Joins Taking forever on table with 60 matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936271/sql-joins-taking-forever-on-table-with-60-matches)

I have dropped the performance of the query from infinity to about 8 minutes by altering the FROM clause and some of the filters.

The sql changed from:

```
SELECT 
ad.acct_lv2 AS IFRS_lvl2,
ad.acct_lv3 AS IFRS_lvl3,
ad.acct_lv4 AS IFRS_lvl4,
ad.acct_lv6 AS IFRS_lvl6,
--(CASE WHEN tb.pl_date = cal.curr_me_date THEN cal.date END) as Reporting_Cycle_This,
--(CASE WHEN tb.pl_date = cal.prev_me_date THEN cal.date END) as Reporting_Cycle_Last,
--(CASE WHEN tb.pl_date = cal.prev_me_date THEN cal.date END) as Reporting_Cycle_Previous,
null as Total,
null as Balance_default_dim,
null as Balance_proxy_dim,
0 as percentage_bal_proxy_applied,
'1 Table Data' as rowType 
FROM TrialBal tb 
INNER JOIN Partition p ON p.partition_code = tb.partition_code
    AND p.entity = tb.entity
LEFT OUTER JOIN ActDetail ah ON tb.actNum = ad.actNum
    AND tb.cpny = ad.cpny
    AND tb.pl_date = ad.pl_date
    AND ad.source = 'Ground0'
--LEFT OUTER JOIN CalendarEngine cal on tb.pl_date = cal.curr_me_date OR tb.pl_date = cal.prev_me_date
    --AND tb.entity = cal.entity
WHERE tb.pl_date = '2014-04-30'
AND tb.entity = 'My_entity'
GROUP BY ad.acct_lv2, ad.acct_lv3, ad.acct_lv4, ad.acct_lv6, --tb.actNum, tb.cpny, 
    CASE WHEN tb.pl_date = cal.curr_me_date THEN cal.date END,
    CASE WHEN tb.pl_date = cal.prev_me_date THEN cal.date END,
    CASE WHEN tb.pl_date = cal.prev_me_date THEN cal.date END
```

to

```
SELECT 
ad.acct_lv2 AS IFRS_lvl2,
ad.acct_lv3 AS IFRS_lvl3,
ad.acct_lv4 AS IFRS_lvl4,
ad.acct_lv6 AS IFRS_lvl6,
(CASE WHEN tb.pl_date = cal_1.curr_me_date THEN cal_1.date END) as Reporting_Cycle_This,
(CASE WHEN tb.pl_date = cal_2.prev_me_date THEN cal_2.date END) as Reporting_Cycle_Last,
(CASE WHEN tb.pl_date = cal_2.prev_me_date THEN cal_2.date END) as Reporting_Cycle_Previous,
null as Total,
null as Balance_default_dim,
null as Balance_proxy_dim,
0 as percentage_bal_proxy_applied,
'1 Table Data' as rowType 
FROM Partition p  
LEFT OUTER JOIN TrialBal tb 
    ON tb.pl_date = '2014-04-30'
    AND tb.entity = 'My_entity'
    AND p.partition_code = tb.partition_code
    AND p.entity = tb.entity
LEFT OUTER JOIN ActDetail ah ON tb.actNum = ad.actNum
    AND tb.cpny = ad.cpny
    AND tb.pl_date = ad.pl_date
    AND ad.source = 'Ground0'
LEFT OUTER JOIN CalendarEngine cal_1 on tb.pl_date = cal_1.curr_me_date 
    AND tb.entity = cal_1.entity
LEFT OUTER JOIN CalendarEngine cal_2 on tb.pl_date = cal_2.curr_me_date 
    AND tb.entity = cal_2.entity
GROUP BY ad.acct_lv2, ad.acct_lv3, ad.acct_lv4, ad.acct_lv6, cal_1.date, cal_2.date
```

This was a change recommended by a DBA, but why the drastic improvement?  TrialBal had 8 million+ rows, how does moving this table into the OUTER JOIN and away from the FROM clause make such a difference?  Wouldn't the Sybase optimiser analyse the most efficient execution path?  And is it a good rule going forward to have the FROM clause reference the smallest table when building the query?

Comment: Have you tried changing only the FROM clause and keeping the filters as they were? I agree that the optimizer should do this by itself. Also, i think that the second version with the LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN produces a different result.

Comment: @Martin I removed the CalanderEngine joins just to test the execution times (without waiting forever!). There are differences:    
Original sql with INNER:                        37 secs  
    Update, replace INNER with OUTER:              209 secs  
    Update, move Partiton to FROM (filters as is):  36 secs  
    Update, move filters:                           38 secs  
  
Incidentally, solved my original problem.  Transposition error in the Tech Spec links each TrialBal record to 30 CalendarEngine records instead of one.  Now executes in 80 secs or so which is *brilliant*!

Comment: SO comment editing tips are clearly meant for someone with more brainpower and patience than me.....

Comment: Its because, when table with higher record is moved in outer clause, extra records gets filtered right at the beginning of sql procession. Ideally joining order comes into picture i.e. tables with less records should be in inner clause and order of join should be a -> b -> c-> . where table a is having lesser rows  than b and table b has lesser rows than c

Comment: The where clause applies to the whole resultset; the on clause only applies to the join in question.

In the example supplied, all of the additional conditions related to fields on the inner side of the join - so in this example, the two queries are effectively identical.

However, if you had included a condition on a value in the table in the outer side of the join, it would make a significant difference.